# planning_scene_warehouse_viewer crash

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I've been working with the planning_scene_warehouse_viewer for a while now without any problems. However today it started to crash on start-up and has remained this way with Real Robot Data, with simulated data, and even after remaking the files from the Planning Description Configuration Wizard. Is there a way to reinstall the planning_scene_warehouse_viewer or rollback whatever I did to break it?

Kind Regards,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59289/planning_scene_warehouse_viewer-crash/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2013-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found that deleting database files in the HOME/.ros/ directory can help fix some issues (I would copy them somewhere just in case you really need them).

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2013-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-03-26**:
Thanks sedwards, this worked like a charm! Cheers :D